# Moving Statefulsets with PV between K8s clusters

Tags: kubernetes, cloud, cluster-computing, google-kubernetes-engine

I am looking to migrate from old GKE clusters to the new Alias IP, however I need to migrate my statefulsets and their PersistentVolumeClaims to the new GKE clusters. I can't seem to find a good answer anywhere stating it's possible, but I imagine it should be as long as it's within the same region. Both new/old k8s cluster still in the same GCP Project, and same Region.

I've searched, but can't find an answer and I can't figure out how to recreate the statefulset without creating a new PV.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into the [Volume Snapshots and volume snapshot content](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volume-snapshots/) direction.

> Similar to how API resources PersistentVolume and
>   PersistentVolumeClaim are used to provision volumes for users and
>   administrators, VolumeSnapshotContent and VolumeSnapshot API resources
>   are provided to create volume snapshots for users and administrators.
>
> A VolumeSnapshotContent is a snapshot taken from a volume in the
>   cluster that has been provisioned by an administrator. It is a
>   resource in the cluster just like a PersistentVolume is a cluster
>   resource.
>
> A VolumeSnapshot is a request for snapshot of a volume by a user. It
>   is similar to a PersistentVolumeClaim.

Example of Volume Snapshot Contents:

```
apiVersion: snapshot.storage.k8s.io/v1alpha1 kind: VolumeSnapshotContent metadata:   name: new-snapshot-content-test spec:   snapshotClassName: csi-hostpath-snapclass   source:
    name: pvc-test
    kind: PersistentVolumeClaim   volumeSnapshotSource:
    csiVolumeSnapshotSource:
      creationTime:    1535478900692119403
      driver:          csi-hostpath
      restoreSize:     10Gi
      snapshotHandle:  7bdd0de3-aaeb-11e8-9aae-0242ac110002
```

Example of VolumeSnapshot:

```
apiVersion: snapshot.storage.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: VolumeSnapshot
metadata:
  name: new-snapshot-test
spec:
  snapshotClassName: csi-hostpath-snapclass
  source:
    name: pvc-test
    kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
```

[Volume Snapshot Alpha for Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/10/09/introducing-volume-snapshot-alpha-for-kubernetes/) was introduces in v1.12. This feature allows creating/deleting volume snapshots, and the ability to create new volumes from a snapshot natively using the Kubernetes API.